# "g++: Command not found" when building sevensquare with make

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install sevensquare so I can mirror my phone to my computer but I recieve errors. Can anyone make some sense of this?

```
sam@sam-System-Product-Name:~/sevensquare$ make
mkdir -p build
(cd build && qmake -o Makefile ../seven-square.pro)
./contributes/generate-keymap.sh
Generate keymap header from src/keycodes.h...58 key map generated in src/keymap-generated.h.
(cd build && make)
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sam/sevensquare/build'
Makefile:209: warning: overriding commands for target `moc_adbfb.cpp'
Makefile:204: warning: ignoring old commands for target `moc_adbfb.cpp'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../../sevensquare -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I../../sevensquare -I. -o main.o ../src/main.cpp
make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/sevensquare/build'
make: *** [app] Error 2
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ compiler is not installed on your system.
Run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```